# Routing Algorithm with Spatial SQL

Tags: sql, multithreading, delphi, routes, mysql-spatial

currently, I search for a solution to speed up my code. I have a DB with different geometrical components (Points, Polygons). Each Structure is given by several properties called Con_Number (default: 0), LayerName, individual Index (ObjectIndex). 
Thereby the Con_Number of each instance should be the same value for ...

- Structures which are overlapping on the same layer.
- Structures which are overlapping on neighbouring layers.

I used the STIntersects command to get overlapping instances.

`sqlString := 
'declare @g geometry select @g = Geom from obj where ObjectIndex = :index 
select ObjectIndex, Con_Number from obj WITH(index(idx_Spatial)) where Geom.STIntersects(@g) = 1 and 
ObjectLayerName in (' + QuotedStrList(neighbourLayers) + ')';`

I tried to perform this algorithm in a parallel loop going through all elements of a certain layer. Afterwards, I run the SqlCommand for each instance on a separate Connection/Query. 
The result will be handled differently depending on the number of different con_numbers. Last but not least, the Con_number of overlapping structures will be updated.

1. Step: Find all overlapping elements!
2. Step: Update Con_Number for overlapping elements!

   ```
   Parallel.ForEach<Integer>(indexList)
         .NumTasks(ThreadCount).Execute(
         procedure(const item: Integer)
   var
       Con_Number: Integer; 
       Con_List: TIntegerList;
   begin
   //Create TADOConnection and TADOQueries

       // 1.STEP: get signals of all overlapping elements
       ADOQueryOverlap.SQL.Text := sqlString;
       ADOQueryOverlap.ParamCheck := True;
       ADOQueryOverlap.Parameters.ParamByName('index').DataType := ftInteger;
       ADOQueryOverlap.Parameters.ParamByName('index').Value := item;
       ADOQueryOverlap.Open;
       ADOQueryOverlap.First;

       while not ADOQueryOverlap.Eof do
       begin
         indexThreadList.add(ADOQueryOverlap.FieldByName('ObjectIndex')
           .AsInteger);
         Con_Number:= ADOQueryOverlap.FieldByName('Con_Number').AsInteger;
         if (Con_List.IndexOf(Con_Number) < 0) and (Con_Number > 0) then
         begin
           Con_List.add(Con_Number);
         end;
         ADOQueryOverlap.next;
       end;

   //2. STEP UPDATE CON_NUMBER

   if indexThreadList.Count > 0 then
   begin
     // elements have no Con_Number -> Assign new Con_Number to overlapping elements
     if signalList.Count = 0 then
     begin
       InterlockedIncrement(FId);
       ADOQueryWriteBack.SQL.Text := 'update obj set Con_Number = ' +
         FId.ToString + ' where ObjectIndex in (' +
         indexThreadList.AsString + ')';
       ADOQueryWriteBack.ExecSQL;
     end;
     // one Con_Number exist -> write that number to all other objects
     if signalList.Count = 1 then
     begin
       ADOQueryWriteBack.SQL.Text := 'update obj set Con_Number = ' +
         Con_List.Items[0].ToString + ' where ObjectIndex in (' +
         indexThreadList.AsString + ')';
       ADOQueryWriteBack.ExecSQL;
     end;
     // more than 1 Con_Number exists -> Take one Con_Number and overwrite other Con_Numbers 
     if signalList.Count > 1 then
     begin
       ADOQueryWriteBack.SQL.Text := 'update obj set Con_Number = ' +
         Con_List.Items[0].ToString + ' where ObjectIndex in (' +
         indexThreadList.AsString + ') or Con_Number in (' +
         Con_List.GetListAsStringFromIndex(1) + ')';
       ADOQueryWriteBack.ExecSQL;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Currently, I try to get a better performance. Furthermore, the threads are crashing after a while (several hours). 
Do you think Multithreading is suitable for my application? Do you have other improvement ideas?

Comment: I can understand that you may need a database to store library shapes and final result, but you are using one throughout, including for intermediate calculations. Databases have big overheads and this is bound to be slow not least because a database is an external application that you communicate with. I would try and use classes instead wherever possible, restricting DB usage to the essential parts at the beginning and end of the algorithm, so that all working is internal to your program.

Comment: Rather than doing lots of individual updates write the changes you need to a temp table in the database (write in batches for better performance) and then do all the updates at once via a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! 
Sounds logical - I will try to make one final Update process.